# vuejs - Caching searchresults of table based on multiple filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using vuejs for this project, but this problem is not necessarily connected - but if there is a vue-way, I would prefer that.

I'm building a table, that enables the user to have per-column-filters (in this case simple `input`s). The columns are dynamic, so is the amount of data (thousands of rows, but less than 100.000 entries).

```
// example data
var columns = ['id', 'title', 'date', 'colour']
var data = [{ id: 1, title: 'Testentry 1', date: '2017-02-21T07:10:55.124Z', colour: 'green'}]
```

Here is the problem: I'm iterating over the columns, checking if a search-input exists, and if so, I try to filter the data based on the searchquery. In case of the ID, the time complexity is `O(n)`. If I know search for a title additionally, I can reuse the result of the first searchquery, dramatically reducing the amount of data has to be looked at.

The searchqueries are stored in an object `search`, and the filtered data is a computed property, that gets updated whenever `search` changes. The way how that works though is, that if I change the searchquery for `title`, it would re-evaluate the searchquery even for the ID, although the searchquery for that didn't change.

This would require some kind of caching of data filtered for each column. And only the proceeding columns need to be queried upon.

edit: added code for the filtering:

```
filteredRows () {
  var rows = this.data
  for (var i = 0; i < this.columns.length; i++) {
    var column = this.columns[i].name
    var search = this.tSearch[column]

    if (!search && search.length === 0) continue

    console.log(column + ': ' + ' (' + search + ') -> ' + rows.length)
    rows = _.filter(rows, (row) => {
      var value = '' + row[column]
      value.search(search) > -1
    })
  }

  return rows
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code for the computed property?

Comment: @Justin: Sure, I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion, but did you try to use a watcher to get old and new value of input.

```
data: function() {
  return {
    propertyToWatch: 'something'
  }
},
computed: {
  ...
},
watch: {
  'propertyToWatch': function (val, oldVal) {
    console.log(oldVal); // logs old value
    console.log(val); // logs current value
    // here you can call a function and send both of these args and detect diff
  }
},
....
```

Comment: The watch doesn't seem work like that on deep properties. The new value is always the same for the new value, and just watching the object rather than the property on the object doesn't help me.

Comment: It was a thought, sorry I couldn't help. If I think of something else I'll edit.